# Authorization Failed

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

i will get below error retrieving management group by rest api azure.

{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read' over scope '/providers/Microsoft.Management' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your client mentioned in the error does not have the `Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read` action permission to list the management groups.

To solve the issue, navigate to the portal, search for the `Management groups`, click the `details` like below.

[image]

Then in the `Access control (IAM)`, add your client(user/service principal) as an RBAC role e.g. `Management Group Reader`, `Management Group Contributor`.

[image]

After a while to take effect, then you can get the token to call the REST API, it will work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First find the AppId from the object ID in the error, you can use cloudShell powerhell.

Connect-AzureAD

Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectIds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xde8P.png)

Then you can go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> find the app using DisplayName above. Give permissions to that appId for what ever the resource you are trying to access

Comment: > Give permissions to that appId for what ever the resource you are trying to access

This part is always the most confusing. How can that be done without magic?